# How to set a default value for one column in SQL based on another column

Tags: sql

I'm working with an old SQL 2000 database and I don't have a whole lot of SQL experience under my belt. When a new row is added to one of my tables I need to assign a default time value based off of a column for work category.

For example, work category A would assign a time value of 1 hour, category B would be 2 hours, etc...

It should only set the value if the user does not manually enter the time it took them to do the work. I thought about doing this with a default constraint but I don't think that will work if the default value has a dependency.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use a trigger on Insert.

Just check to see if a value has been assigned, and if not, go grab the correct one and use it.

Comment: do you know if creating such triggers affects the database insert speed in any way?

Comment: That's dependent on the logic and/or query you have in the trigger. I would expect there to be no user discernible impact though.  Though, if you're not using SQL 2000 (as indicated in the OP), I'd look at using a user-defined scaler function in the DEFAULT attribute rather than a trigger.

Answer (score 6):

Use a trigger as suggested by Stephen Wrighton:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [myTable_TriggerName] ON dbo.myTable FOR INSERT        
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
UPDATE myTable
SET
    timeValue = '2 hours' -- assuming string values
where ID in (
    select ID
    from INSERTED
    where
        timeValue = ''
        AND workCategory = 'A'
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to write the trigger so it will handle multi-row inserts. Do not process one row at a time in a trigger or assume only one row will be in the inserted table.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is to define a column definition based on another column you can do something like this:

```
create table testable 
(
    c1 int, 
    c2 datetime default getdate(), 
    c3 as year(c2)
);

insert into testable (c1) select 1

select * from testable;
```

Your result set should look like this :

```
c1 | c2                      | c3
1  | 2013-04-03 17:18:43.897 | 2013
```

As you can see AS (in the column definition) does the trick ;) Hope it helped.

Comment: 'AS' doesn't seem to be valid in PostgreSQL.

Comment: The question was for SQL Server 2000, it didn't mentioned anything about PostgreSQL. Sorry.

Comment: Worked like a charm to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, trigger.

Naturally, instead of hard-coding the defaults, you'll look them up from a table.

Expanding on this, your new table then becomes the work_category table (id, name, default_hours), and you original table maintains a foreign key to it, transforming fom 
(id, work_category, hours) to (id, work_category_id, hours).

Answer (score 1):

So, for example, in a TAG table (where tags are applied to posts) if you want to count one tag as another...but default to counting new tags as themselves, you would have a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_Tag_Insert]
   ON  [dbo].[Tag]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE dbo.Tag 
   SET [CountAs] = I.[ID]
   FROM INSERTED AS I
   WHERE I.[CountAs] IS NULL
   AND dbo.Tag.ID = I.ID
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

1. triggers
2. default value or binding (this should work with a dependency)

Triggers seem well explained here, so I won't elaborate. But generally I try and stay away from triggers for this sort of stuff, as they are more appropriate for other tasks

"default value or binding" can be achieved by creating a function e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ComponentContractor_SortOrder] ()
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT MAX(SortOrder) + 5 FROM [dbo].[tblTender_ComponentContractor])
END
```

And then setting the "default value or binding" for that column to ([dbo].ComponentContractor_SortOrder)

Answer (score 0):

Generally I steer away from triggers. Almost all dbms have some sort of support for [constraints.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)

I find them easier to understand , debug and maintain.

Comment: If, as I understand the request, you only want to alter this value at insert, use a constraint.  If you want to change it at any to the row, use a trigger.

Comment: [PostgreSQL constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html) seem to only raise errors, not set a default value.