# Default binding row ID

Tags: sql-server

I have a field in my database table that I want to assign a default binding to. The value should be the same as the generated row ID.

Is it possible to do this in the 'default binding' option of the design view? I am using SQL Server 2008.

Edit: the goal of this is that the copied ID can change later on. The copied field represents the sortingKey of the table. The sorting of the table can be changed by switching the sortingKeys of two rows.

Comment: You are using Sql Server Management Studio, right? Which version?

Comment: For whatever problem you're trying to solve, would it not be possible for a `NULL` to represent "use this row's `ID` column" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a trigger, or you get something close with computed column.  With the example below if `value` is NULL then `idOrValue` will show id, otherwise it will show value.  The difference between what you are asking for is that if value is set back to null, then the computed column will revert to the id versus if this was possible with default then you'd get null back.

**T-SQL**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') is not null DROP TABLE #t1

CREATE TABLE #t1 (
   id INT IDENTITY,
   value INT,
   idOrValue AS coalesce(value, id)
)

INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES
(1), (NULL)

SELECT * FROM #t1
```

**Output**

```
id  value   idOrValue
1   1       1
2   NULL    2
```

Comment: A bit complicated explanation, but this is a fine display of what OP may use if applicable.

Comment: I am going with the TRIGGER solution as this fits my purpose best. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's in `Computed column specification > (Formula)`.
There you have to enter `ID`.

If you're using it as a condition in your WHERE, you should check `Persisted` option and make an appropriate index.

**HOWEVER**, as Damien_The_Unbeliever said, this is really a pointless action. If you want to set it as a default value of a new column, I believe you have to use an AFTER TRIGGER. In that case, you're duplicating [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711159/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-one-column-in-sql-based-on-another-column).

Comment: That would force it to *always* be equal to the `ID` column, which is as close to pointless as you could ever wish for. A column with a default can be *altered* in an individual row, which I presume is behavior that the OP is seeking.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: exactly my thinking. mea culpa, I wanted a score. I will update my answer.