# how to create an order column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

i want an order info for every row in my table. the following is my table. ID column is identity and its primary key. Order column is computed from id column.

```
   ID     --      Name     --     Order
    1             kiwi              1
    2             banana            2
    3             apple             3
```

everything is fine and i have an order column. But i cant switch the orders of rows.
for example i cant say that from now on kiwi's order becomes 2 and banana's order becomes 1 
in other words if we would update a computed column then my problem could be solved.

if i dont create order column as computed column then for every new entry i have to compute largest order so that i can write (largest order) + 1  for new entry's order. But i do not calculate largest number for every entry since it is costly.

So what should i do now?

I ve searched and the solutions i found creating trigger function etc. i do not want to do that too.

Comment: It's not clear: _"if we would update a computed column then i could create order column as computed from ID column and my problem could be solved."_ What does that mean? Why can't you update that `order`-column?`

Comment: is column 'ID'  IDENTITY ??

Comment: you get next order as (largest order) + 1 AS per your Name  Column OR  get largest order from entire Order column ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the order column is computed column. so i cant change it. i have edited my question

Comment: @KrishKvR yes ID is identity. Thats why order cant be identity, if we could create two identity columns in sql server then every thing could be fine for my question

Comment: @HiralNayak i do not want to get next order for every new entry since it is costly or isnt it or is there another way to get that largest number without calculation?

Comment: @bttb you have the solution (find the largest value) but you do not want to apply it: what do you expect from SO people?

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711159/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-one-column-in-sql-based-on-another-column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might not have understood the question - I don't think its very clear.

but why use a counter to order the set, couldnt you just use a timestamp for each order and use that to dictate which order is more recent?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (
                        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
                        Name varchar(50),
                        OrderTime Datetime
                      )

INSERT INTO dbo.TEST (Name,OrderTime)
VALUES ('kiwi',Getdate())

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.TEST
ORDER BY OrderTime
```

if you needed an integer based on the order time you could use a rownumber function to return one;

```
SELECT  *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderTime Desc) as OrderInt 
FROM dbo.TEST
```